# TTL on Ignite 2.5.0 not working

Tags: spring, ignite

I tried enabling TTL for records in Ignite using 2 approaches, but didn't seems to be working. Need help to understand if I am missing something.

```
IgniteCache cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(IgniteCfg.CACHE_NAME);
cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS City (id LONG primary key, name varchar, region varchar)"))
                .getAll();
cache.withExpiryPolicy(new CreatedExpiryPolicy(new Duration(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 10)))
                .query(new SqlFieldsQuery(
                        "INSERT INTO City (id, name, region) VALUES (?, ?, ?)").setArgs(1, "Forest Hill1", "GLB"))
                .getAll();
```

So you see above I created table in Cache and inserted record mentioning expiry TTL for 10 seconds, but seems that it never expires.

I tried another approach of rather than setting TTL while inserting the record, I mentioned in CacheConfiguration while I initialize Ignite, below is the code sample

```
Ignition.setClientMode(true);
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

// Disabling peer-class loading feature.
cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(false);

CacheConfiguration ccfg = createCacheConfiguration();
cfg.setCacheConfiguration(ccfg);
ccfg.setEagerTtl(true);
ccfg.setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 5)));

TcpCommunicationSpi commSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
cfg.setCommunicationSpi(commSpi);

TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder tcpDiscoveryFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
String[] addresses = { "127.0.0.1" };
tcpDiscoveryFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList(addresses));
TcpDiscoverySpi discoSpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
discoSpi.setIpFinder(tcpDiscoveryFinder);
cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discoSpi);

return Ignition.start(cfg);
```

> Executing Ignite locally (not as in memory) as my final goal is to be able to connect to same Ignite from multiple instances of app or even multiple apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignite SQL currently doesn't interact with expiry policies and doesn't update TTL. There is a Feature Request for that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7687.